# Encrypted password in Berkeley DB for vsftpd using pam_userdb.so

Tags: authentication, ftp, pam, vsftpd

I am trying to install a vsftpd with some virtual users using the Berkeley DB. I have mainly followed this guide: http://www.neant.ro/2012/04/secure-ftp-with-vsftpd/ . Everything works fine, but I want to have the passwords hashed inside the database. I am using CentOS 6.3 with glibc 2.12.

From the manpage of pam_userdb.so I assume that I can use what crypt provides. If we take a look of crypt(3) manpage we can use SHA-256 and SHA-512. I would to use one of those.

My doubt is how to implement it. From what I know i need to go to my pam.d file and edit and add the argument crypt but... which value should I give it? 5 for SHA-256? 6 for SHA-512?

```
auth    sufficient pam_userdb.so db=/path/to/db/virtual-users crypt=?
account sufficient pam_userdb.so db=/path/to/db/virtual-users crypt=?
session sufficient pam_loginuid.so
```

Now I need the password in SHA-256/SHA-512 inside the database. Which is the correct way to get the hash? I suppose I have to use the crypt function. However, I need to get it using Ruby, is there any way?

Thanks in advance for the help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way. You should say `crypt=crypt` (other options are rejected) but `mod_userdb` won't accept non-DES hashes, at least, not until you get a version of PAM that has [this fix](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/pam-developers/2013-February/000360.html) in it (Ubuntu Saucy doesn't, for one).

I, for one, compiled my own PAM to have that fix.

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you please share with me your compiled version or telling me how to do myself? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is [fixed](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/linux-pam.git/tree/modules/pam_userdb/pam_userdb.c#n218). Debian Jessie's version 1.1.8-3 of libpam-modules seems fixed too.

To insert a line use db5.3-util or similar:

`{ echo user; echo hash; } | db5.3_load -T -t hash /tmp/passwd.db`

To generate a crypt-valid strong `hash`:

`echo pass|mkpasswd -s -m sha-512`

The "debug" option of this pam module is useful (check /var/log/auth.log) as is [pamtester](http://pamtester.sourceforge.net/)